# Errors as Unbound variable in Lisp Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

I just type simple code like

```
(define pi 3.14)
(* 2 pi)
```

and I always get the error message like title,here is the details:

```
(define p 2)
(+ 1 p)
;Unbound variable: p
;To continue, call RESTART with an option number:
; (RESTART 6) => Specify a value to use instead of p.
; (RESTART 5) => Define p to a given value.
; (RESTART 4) => Return to read-eval-print level 4.
; (RESTART 3) => Return to read-eval-print level 3.
; (RESTART 2) => Return to read-eval-print level 2.
; (RESTART 1) => Return to read-eval-print level 1.
;Start debugger? (y or n): n
```

I am using GNU scheme interceptor, and when I typed

```
(define p 2)
    (+ 1 p)
```

I use C-x C-e to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:  "C-M-z, which evaluates all of the expressions in the [highlighted] region, and M-o, which evaluates the entire buffer." More [here.](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-Scheme-Evaluation.html#Edwin-Scheme-Evaluation)